# When hot code replace fails, the Jboss restarts the server by default

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have configured the Eclipse to `Restart` automatically the Jboss server on `hot code replace failed` by default.

With this configuration, the server is restarting continuously when I code, and my Eclipse loses performance.

I have clicked on `Do not show error when hot code replace fails` after set it to `Restart`, and consequently the following window in the image does not appear anymore.

I would like to change it in `Terminate` instead of `Restart`. But I do not find the option to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have configured the option in the application Reload menu of Jboss, it works.

[image]